# How to Parse Out 1543 Tommy by Regex

Tags: regex, parsing

This regex code (below) can work on address lines. For example: `111 N Main St` comes out as `MAIN`. Basically, It omits `dr`,`ave`,`lane` etc as well as directional terms after number such as N,S,N,E.

However, if the address line is `110 Main Table` (does not contain keywords like `street`,`st`,`lane`,`blvd`), it shows the value as null. I want the outcome to be `Main Table`. Another example is `110 N Main Table` (again this does not have key values such as `street`,`st`,`lane`,`bldvd` etc). I need it to come out as `MAIN TABLE` again (in short, get rid of directional term (N) and since there is no keyword like `street`,`st`,`lane`,`blvd`) take the whole thing (Main Table)

I wonder how I can adjust my regex based on these criteria

Regex Code:

```
(?<=\d\b)\s*(?:N|S|W|E|North|South|East|West|NE)\s(.?)\s(?=drive|dr|ave|avenue|lane|ln|loop|hwy|circle|cir|plaza|pl|terrace|blvd|boulevard|pkwy|drive|dr|way|road|court|Parkway|run|st|ct|terr|rd|street)?
```

Comment: Should it match in the middle of a string? Should it only match if the "1543" is present? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Assume that I have 100 records , they all start with numbers ([0-9] then space then a string of text (ex: 1543 Tommy or 12312312 SRAR or 92131 toms hamze or 11 seka)

Comment: Can you add under your question what have you tried so far? Do you know how to [write regex](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: yes, please see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is only part of the picture here. Your best bet is to capture the parts like so:

```
^(\d+)(?: [NS]?[WE]?)?(\w+(?: \w+)) (\w+)$
```

<sup>*Note: you can omit the anchors `^` and `$` if you want.*</sup>

*Then*, after that, you can use the language's string comparison operator on each possibility:

```
$3 == "foo" || $3 == "bar" || ... // should look something like this in C-like languages
```

Or, alternatively, if your language supports it:

```
$3 in ["foo", "bar", ...]
```

Then you can just return `$2`. Putting it all together for a JS example:

```
s.replace(/^(\d+)(?: [NS]?[WE]?)?(\w+(?: \w+)) (\w+)$/, (match, $1, $2, $3) => $3 in ["foo", "bar", ...] ? $2 : null));
```

Unfortunately, there really isn't any way of doing this without typing out all of the possibilities.